# angular2: routerLinks are not pressable

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have followed the official quickstart pages to create my first `Router`.

However at the end the navigation links do nothing when I click them.

Here is what i have done:

```
app.routing.ts:

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'push',
    component: PushComponent
  }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing
  ],
```

what else should i configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine, what does your `routerLink` look like? It should look like one of these:

```
<a routerLink="/push">Push me</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/push']">Push me</a>
```

Oh and make sure you have `<base href="/">` in your `index.html`.

If you're still having trouble you'll need to give more details, preferably create a plnkr.